# 1 switch - 2 Lights

Tags: switch, light

I'm replacing a switch, in a mobile home, just to update and have a white one. I removed old switch, which was a self-enclosed box switch. What is the right way to wire it. I wired it up to new switch but when I flipped the switch, the breaker flipped. So, I'm doing something wrong here, need some help.

Comment: How many cables are present at the switch location?

Comment: Did you record (picture) how the old switch was wired?